# capture div using canvas gives blank image for graph in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, canvas

i had try to capture div. it take content and images both in capture and saved. but when i try to capture a graph using canvas it give blank image. it take height and width for image but it show white blank image.

i had use JPower Graph

this is add in index file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function capture() {
        $('#target').html2canvas({
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                //Submit the form manually
                document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>
```

this is save.php

```
$filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

//Decode the string
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//Save the image
file_put_contents('img.png', $unencodedData);
```